# Create unique list from column in multiple dataframes, create excel workbooks based off that, and put rows from dataframes on different worksheets?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image: df1]

[image: df2]

So here, 
I have 2 data frames, each has Name1 and Name2. I am trying to create an excel sheet named BOB + SAM, have that data frames name as the sheet name and the one record that is it. Ryan Connor is in both data frames, so I want to create an excel file named Ryan + Connor, have data frame 1 record on sheet 1 (named something) and data frames 2 records on sheet 2

In my actual use case, I will have many more than 2 dataframes.

The below code works properly for 1 data frame however not for more than 1

```
names=df['A'].unique().tolist()
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import os
path="/name"
os.chdir(path)
for i in names:
    writer = ExcelWriter(str(i)+'.xlsx')
    i=pd.DataFrame(df.loc[df['A']==i])
    i.to_excel(writer)
```

Comment: This really isn't clear to me at all. Please also don't link to external resources for crucial data, they could expire. Please make sure the question is self-contained.

Comment: @roganjosh hopefully I can explain it a bit better... I have a bunch of SQL codes that I am writing into pandas to create multiple dataframes (df1,df2,df3..etc). All of those dataframes will have columns named Name1 and Name2. I want to take all of the data from all of the dataframes for these 2 columns and find ALL of the unique combinations. create excel files for each of these combinations and have all of the data that matches within the excel file (different tabs for different dataframes)

Comment: so in the scenario above,  I am trying to create excel files for all of the unique name combos (name1 & name2) from above - "Bob + Sam.xlsx", "Paul + Beth.xlsx", "Ryan + Connor.xlsx" - I then want to have the matching data inserted into the appropriate Excel file, so for Ryan Connor, he would have data from dataframe 1 and dataframe 2 so it would have 2 separate tabs with the data